# Using apply in dplyr-grouped dataframe fails

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to apply a function to a grouped dataframe with dplyr. The vector-output of this function should then be assigned to a new variable in the grouped dataframe.

```
require(dplyr)
data = data.frame(Var1='a',Var2=rep(1,5))
data  %.% 
  group_by(Var1) %.% 
  mutate(Var3 = sapply(seq(1,length(Var2)), function(x) x))
```

I fail to understand why this dplyr-code fails with message:

"Error in mutate_impl(.data, named_dots(...), environment()) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name"

Comment: Works for me, even if grouping by a variable with one level is a bit strange. `dplyr` has changed a lot, try to update first and post `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: I can't replicate your error - you probably just need to update `dplyr` to the latest version

Comment: Yep, I would guess it's because ```dplyr``` isn't up-to-date. You apparently started using it when ```%.%``` was the pipe operator, instead of ```%>%```. The old one still works, but ```%>%``` has become the norm now.

Comment: Thank, I overlooked the outdated package.

Comment: Still, what I was trying to achieve in the first place does not work: `data %.%   mutate(Var3 = sapply(seq(1,length(Var2)), function(x) prod(1 + Var2[1:x])))`

Comment: This fails, because Var2 is not known inside sapply. I cant really figure out a smart way of doing this without a loop..

Comment: Are you trying to do a cumulative product?  See `cumprod`.  You might consider asking another question about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: This gave me back a result: `data %.% mutate(Var3 = sapply(seq_along(Var2), function(x){
g <- get("Var2", data); prod(1 + g[1:x]) }))`.  Does that help?